# How can I get word selection event in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am building an application in which user can select a word from the article displayed on a webpage, I save that word in the database for later use.

Which event can I use so that I can get which word the user has selected. I am using AngularJS. Below is a code which I found in jQuery, how can I write equivalent AngularJS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var p = $('p');
    p.css({ cursor: 'pointer' });

    p.dblclick(function(e) {
        var range = window.getSelection() || document.getSelection() || document.selection.createRange();
        var word = $.trim(range.toString());
        if(word != '') {
            alert(word);
        }
        range.collapse();
        e.stopPropagation();
    });

});
```

Comment: You may want to look at how to write [directives](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and well events are all the same, angular is just another javascript framework.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to wrap it inside a directive:

```
app.directive('p', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      element.css({ cursor: 'pointer' });
      element.on('dblclick', function(e) {
        var range = window.getSelection() || document.getSelection() || document.selection.createRange();
        var word = range.toString().trim();
        if(word !== '') {
          console.log(word);
        }
        e.stopPropagation();
      });      
    }
  }
});
```